# Apache RewriteRule servererror 500

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've build a one page website that has a language selector. With this selector the url changes to www.domain.com/en (or what ever language was selected).

On my developer server it all works fine, but when i move it to the productionserver I get a Internal Server Error 500.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(scripts|images|external|css|img|js|downloads)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Can anyone the what the problem is?

Apache version on the live hosting is 2.2.15 and on my developer hosting 2.2.3

Comment: Sorry, the last RewriteRule was a test (witch didn't resolve my problem). The original is RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?$ [NC,L]

Comment: Do you have any other rules ?

Comment: Nope... Well there is of course the "RewriteEngine On" at the beginning, but besides that, nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a RewriteBase for the directory, so in this case `RewriteBase /`

Edit: (changed answer to actually match the solution arrived at in comments)

Comment: nope, same result...

BTW.i Found this in the logfile: [Thu Jun 30 12:37:52 2016] [warn] RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-s' is not supported and will be ignored.
[Thu Jun 30 12:37:52 2016] [warn] RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-l' is not supported and will be ignored.
[Thu Jun 30 12:37:52 2016] [warn] RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-d' is not supported and will be ignored.

Comment: I guess the NC in condition started in Apache 2.4.X. What happens if you do nothing but `RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]`?

Comment: Nope, the NC condition also works in 2.2.3 as my testserver works fine with these settings... When i try your suggestion i get "The requested URL /home/sites/site47351/subdomains/dripaknx/index.php was not found on this server." Strange, there really is an index.php there

Comment: Set a `RewriteBase` to that directory? So `RewriteBase /` if that is your root directory.

Comment: YES!.... i used this :

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(scripts|images|external|css|img|js|downloads)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the last `$` in your last `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(scripts|images|external|css|img|js|downloads)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php? [NC,L]
```

`$` is a reserved character for the second parameter of `RewriteRule` (ie: `$1`, `$2`, `$3` ...). If you need a `$` in your query string you should escape it `\$`.

Comment: THNX, but the last RewriteRule was an attempt to resolve it. The original that causes the error is indeed "RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php? [NC,L]"

Comment: Sorry I can't reproduce your error with this file, on my configuration it's working normally.

Comment: You can try to remove one rule at a time to see which one is causing this issue. Or you can try to turn your apache log into debug mode to get a more precise error.

Comment: Yes, i already had a look at the logfiles: "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., ". So, it is an internal redirect loop. But that doesn't bring me anyfuther. My htacces skills do not reach that far... I also tried to pinpoint the rule that causes the problem... When i remove the RewriteCond rules (all three of them) i get a 404. When I remove the last RewriteRule i also get a 404.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not excluded the destination from your rule, that is why the rule is causinp an infinite loop error

Replace your rule with

```
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php).*)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: THNX for your suggestion. I tried the following:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(scripts|images|external|css|img|js|downloads)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php).*)$ index.php [NC,L]

But helaas, that didn't do the trick either. Still getting the 500

Comment: Then, probably you have other rewrite rules. I have tested this and its working ok now.